# Throw exception and set value to 0

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that check if the given argument x is < 0, if It is, it throws an exception and sets x to 0 otherwise it just returns x.

```
InvalidParameterException
```

this is the code that I have

```
    private static double mayBePositive(double x, String msg){
    if (x < 0){
        x = 0;
        throw new InvalidParameterException(msg);
    }
    return x;
}
```

The question is should I use the try block? And what is the best way to do this, I know that the code above doesn't work properly, but I can't figure one this out.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem: You want to do X, you've thought of the above (Y) as a way to do it, and now you're asking about a problem you're having implementing Y. What's X?

Comment: Setting `x` to 0 and throwing an exception seams overkill to me. If an exception is thrown, especially an `InvalidArgumentException` or an `InvalidParameterException`, you know the argument passed in is invalid. Setting `x` to 0 means the value is now valid, and the exception is useless. Throwing an exception renders setting the value useless, and setting the value renders throwing the exception useless.

Comment: "I know that the code above doesn't work properly" What do you expect the method to do?

Answer (score 5):

Your method cannot both throw an exception and return an updated `x`. It can *either* throw an exception, or it can return a value. These are mutually-exclusive options. Setting `x` to `0` in the case where you throw is called a "dead store" (because `x` ceases to exist when control leaves the method, thus the value stored in it is never used for anything).

It would be possible to make it sort of do both by having it accept a single-entry array or a custom wrapper object, which would then let it use a side-effect to change the value of that entry in the array or a property on that wrapper object before throwing the exception, but it's unlikely to be the right way to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: That makes sense, so if x is -1 i can't throw the exception AND set the value to 0 at the same time.

Comment: @Exzlanttt: Nope. :-)

Comment: @Exzlanttt You can from the callsite, but then this method seems useless.